# how to delete only unique values from a mysql table

Tags: mysql

I need to delete only unique values from a table. Something like:

```
delete from clients where title is unique
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using a join with th count for title having count = 1

```
delete c
from clients  c
inner join (
    select title 
    from clients 
    group by title 
    having count(*) = 1

) t on t.title  = c.title
```

Comment: seems it works, thanks. btw - too much code for such a trivial thing.

Comment: as you say  ...  this work ..    ..  and is not properly a trivial  .. things  ..  otherwise  .. why asking for a trivial things ..

Comment: I'm asking because there is no `delete from clients where title is unique` or similar query, and that's a shame for a serious db system. Doesn't touch you and your great knowledge.

Comment: In sql  some things are not simple ..  ..  the nested subquery retunrn only the title with just  an entry  ..  and the use of  join with nested  subquery  ..  is frequently use for match result set ..  this in not a big query  in sql  ..

Comment: The entire your query should be performed under the hood. For a user, if `user-friendly` attribute is concerned, it should be - `delete where column is unique`.

Comment: You comment have not sense to  me ...  i just answer  to your question .. this is how SQL work